# Jetty-Runner using only one CPU?

Tags: tomcat, jetty, runjettyrun

I have a web-application that does a lot of background-calculation. When I deploy the app in tomcat8 I can see that the Java-Process uses up to 800% of the 12 cores that I have available.

When I run the same application in jetty-runner from the command-line the java-process takes only one CPU (100%).

It seems to me that I did not understand at all how tomcat and the jetty-runner actually run my webapp? I am fairly new to the whole JVM-Thing :-)

Is there a way to tell the jetty-runner to use multple CPUs like tomcat8 does, or am I completley of track here?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You have 12 cores?

Then use Jetty 9.4.2.v20170220, as that's been enhanced for systems above 8 cores, and tested all the way up to 48 cores (so far).

Also, don't use jetty-runner, as that's for ultra simplistic / naive webapp deployment scenarios.

Your needs, as described, are well past role of jetty-runner.

Consider using the jetty-distribution, as that will allow you to tweak the configuration even more for thread pools, selectors, acceptors, etc.